# Connection between eigenvalues of a real matrix A and its norm.

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a connection among norm of a matrix, its eigenvalues and the image of $A$? Specifically if all eigenvalues of a matrix $A$ ($n$ by $n$) have absolute value less than one, can we find a vector $v$ in $ \mathbb{R}^n $ with $||Av||>||v||$?
A simple example of a $2$ by $2$ matrix I am unable to get. Please help.

Comment: Are we including complex eigenvalues?

Comment: Yes. Eigen values could be complex.

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}1/2 & 1 \\ 0 & 1/2\end{pmatrix}$$
Then $1/2$ is the only eigenvalue of $A$. If $v = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$, then $Av = \begin{pmatrix} 3/2 \\ 1/2\end{pmatrix}$, hence $\|Av\| = \sqrt{10}/2 > \sqrt{2} = \|v\|$.

Comment: Thank you for the example. Does the example work only for non diagonalisable matrix? Could you please throw some light on the theory behind this??

Answer (score 0):

$A:=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$.

This has 1 repeated eigenvalue $(\lambda=1)$, but if $v=(0,1)^T$, then $Av = (1,1)^T$, which has larger norm than $v$.

Perhaps the connection you're looking for is through [singular-value-decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition), where $\sigma_1(A)=\|A\|$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\0 &1\end{pmatrix}$, which only has eigenvalue $1$. Then $\| A\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}\| = \|\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}\| = \sqrt{2}$.

However, you can get a restriction on this by assuming for example that $A$ is real and symmetric (or Hermitian). It is then diagonalisable with orthonormal eigenvectors $e_n$, $A(e_n)=\lambda_n e_n$. Assuming $|\lambda_n|<1$ $\forall n$ and expanding $v=\sum v_ne_n$, we find
$$ \|A(v)\|=\| A(\sum v_ne_n)\|=|\sum \lambda_nv_n|\leq\sum|\lambda_nv_n|\leq \sum|v_n|=\|v\|$$

Answer (score 0):

All examples are non-diagonalizable matrices with the same eigenvalues. But it doesn't need to be that way. For example:
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1/2 & 1000 \\ 0 & 1/3\end{bmatrix}$$
Then just select $v=[0 ~~ 1]^T$.

Comment: Ok. It is true for diagonalisable matrices also. Thank you.